# interrupt a MJPG stream

Tags: jquery, mjpeg

I have a MJPEG stream available through a CGI on an AXIS P1347 camera. But for performances reasons, I don't want to retreive it when it shouldn't be shown. Is there a way to interrupt the stream ?

Actually, I'm using the Page Visibility API to check if the page is currently visible. When the page is not visible (minimized for instance), I set the  tag source to "#". It seems to interrupt the stream with FF, albeit with a 30 seconds delay. But with Chrome or Safari, the image isn't displayed anymore but the stream is still retreived.
I'm using another CGI to get a Connections List that shows me if the streams are delivered or not.

Does anybody kowns how to interrupt the stream on Webkit browsers ?
And does anybody knows how to get rid of this annoying 30 seconds delay ?

Thanks in avdance for your great solutions !